# How to use a singleton class of one module in another module in guice?

Tags: java, guice

I want to use a singleton class(which is already present in a module) in an another module without creating a new instance of that class i.e., using that same singleton class instance. Is there any way to do so? The reason why I want to do so is because creating a new instance of the same class will do some things twice which is present in its constructor. The idea is to use what is already present.

Comment: How is it a singleton? By class design, or because it's annotated `@Singleton` in the guice module? Why do you think you get a new instance if you just inject it?

Comment: It's binded as an eagerSingleton in module A. Will the same instance be injected to a class which is binded in module B and has no relation to module A ?

Comment: Yes, it will be the same instance. The fact they are in different modules is irrelevant, provided the modules are added to the same injector.

Comment: Just install both modules in one injector and use you singleton in second module as you do in the first.